# JQuery toggle() html data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried searching for a solution to this but can't seem to find a working answer. I may have missed something obvious.

I have a link to show the latest comments on a status. When the link is clicked the link data changes to "Close" (all good) but when close is then clicked to toggle the DIV  the link data stays "Close", I want it to return to the original text (i.e 3 Comments).

The HTML:

```
<a class="comments" id="coms-<?php echo $statmainID; ?>" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> <?php echo $numComs; ?> Comments</a>

<div id="comss<?php echo $statmainID; ?>" style="display:none;">Comments Here</div>
```

The JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.comments', function(){
        var cID =$(this).attr('id');
        var theID = cID.split("-");
        var divID = theID[1];
        $('#comss'+divID).toggle("slide");
        $('.comments'+divID).html('Close');
        return false;
     });
});
```

As always, any help from you guru's is always appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You're modifying the text of the `.comments` element to "Close", why would it "magically" reappear? This has nothing to do with the `toggle` which just shows/hides elements.

Comment: I just want the "close" text to change back to Comments once the toggle has closed the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data attribute to store the original text. Then you can show it again.

HTML

```
<body> 
    <a class="comments" id="coms-1" href="javascript:;" data-id="comss1" data-text="4 Comments">
        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i> 4 Comments
    </a>
    <div id="comss1" style="display:none;">Comments Here</div>

    <a class="comments" id="coms-2" href="javascript:;" data-id="comss2" data-text="2 Comments">
        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i> 2 Comments
    </a>
    <div id="comss2" style="display:none;">Comments Here</div>
</body>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.comments', function(){
        var cID =$(this).attr('id');
        var theID = cID.split("-");
        var divID = theID[1];
        $('#comss'+divID).toggle("slide");

        var comments =  $('#coms-'+divID);
        if($(comments).text() === "Close"){
            $(comments).html($(comments).data("text"));
        } else {
            $(comments).html('Close');
        }

        return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: The toggle works but no data changes within the link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qjwpq4m6/ It seems to be working. When you click "2 comments" the comments are closed, when You click "close" the text change back to "2 comments" isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: @NOJ75 - Note that your selectors don't match the HTML in the question, there is no `.comments-something` class etc.

Comment: @Zoli I have just changed your var to this     var comments = $('#coms-'+divID); and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: @NOJ75 I see the problem was that I didn't tested it with multiple divs. I'll change my code.

Comment: @Zoli Thank you very much for your help.  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tj7b4zru/1/)

```
var prevText=$(".comments").text();
$(".comments").click(function(){
    if($(this).text().indexOf("Comments")>=0){
        $(this).text("Close");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).text(prevText);
    }
    return false;
});
```

**UPDATE**

[FIDDLE WITH STATIC NUMBER OF COMMENTS](https://jsfiddle.net/tj7b4zru/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. The question has been answered above. But again, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following. Keep the original text in a `data attribute` and show it when on `Close` click.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.comments', function() {
  var cID = $(this).attr('id');
  var theID = cID.split("-");
  var divID = theID[1];
  $('#comss' + divID).toggle("slide");

  if ($(this).html().trim() != 'Close') {
    $(this).data('text', $(this).html());
    $(this).html('Close');
  } else {
    $(this).html($(this).data('text'));
  }

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<a class="comments" id="coms-1" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> 1 Comments</a>
<div id="comss1" style="display:none;">Comments Here</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome. It allows me to keep the Font Awesome icon in place.  Thank you @Azim.